# how do i make the inside concave profile of this basin

Tags: modeling, surface-deform

[image: the 2d picture with measurement for reference]

I am getting stuck on how do i approach this model.
My failed approach:

1. step 1 : created a cylinder with the given dimentions of the model
2. step 2 : tried to subdivide the face and failed
3. step 3 : tried to do something with lattice and still failed cause im not able to subdidve the top face

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/PeNINha) what you're after? Not quite clear from your reference what the inside profile should be.

Comment: What exactly failed when you tried subdividing the top face? Can you show your current imperfect mesh?

Comment: YES!!!!! Robin Betts thats what i am after and how do i achieve it ?